# Caching mechanism cluster environment

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

If we use a static hash map for caching process in a normal class (Not a singelton class)  will it work in cluster environment?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please rephrase it and add more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A static field's value is stored in the memory of the JVM, and each JVM will thus have its own static map. This can be OK, unless you want a unique cache for all the members of the cluster.

Comment: @above: So the value's will not be in sync?

Comment: My name is JB Nizet, not above. And of course not, the values won't be in sync. How would the map know that another similar map exists in other JVMs and that it must synchrnize its values with theirs. A map is just a data structure. It doesn't magically communicate with other maps in a cluster.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you're writing the requirements for a framework like Terracotta : http://terracotta.org/documentation/product-documentation-1page

You're talking about JVM memory sharing